# Algorithm for comparing two images with orientation

Tags: asp.net

hai
     Any algorithm for comparing two images with any orientation? Can any one help?
     Give me some link.

Thank you

Comment: 4 position orientation or with an angle ?

Comment: with an angle. it should compare two x-ray images

Answer (score 1):

[Computer Vision/Computer Graphics Collaboration Techniques](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=KDw7bwVDOZIC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=computer+graphics+algorithm+for+comparing+two+images+based+on+orientation&source=bl&ots=jGk-AAYVdw&sig=f5PrBdv4UXPcd63DBMz-qiR60G8&hl=en&ei=jzHBTdTWBo_qrQfy7enfAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Code to compare two images in c#

```
public bool doImagesMatch(ref Bitmap bmp1, ref Bitmap bmp2)
{
    try
    {
        //create instance or System.Drawing.ImageConverter to convert
        //each image to a byte array
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        //create 2 byte arrays, one for each image
        byte[] imgBytes1 = new byte[1];
        byte[] imgBytes2 = new byte[1];

        //convert images to byte array
        imgBytes1 = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp1, imgBytes2.GetType());
        imgBytes2 = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp2, imgBytes1.GetType());

        //now compute a hash for each image from the byte arrays
        SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] imgHash1 = sha.ComputeHash(imgBytes1);
        byte[] imgHash2 = sha.ComputeHash(imgBytes2);

        //now let's compare the hashes
        for (int i = 0; i < imgHash1.Length && i < imgHash2.Length; i++)
        {
            //loops, found a non-match, exit the loop
            //with a false value
            if (!(imgHash1[i] == imgHash2[i]))
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    //we made it this far so the images must match
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how we can highlight the different portion which is different from the original image. i want to compare two x-ray images.